# I want to install an English language pack in Libreoffice

Tags: software-installation, dictionary, spell-checking

I run Ubuntu, updated and just re-installed Libreoffice but it has only Spanish languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question does not show much research.

Search for available language options:
`apt search libreoffice-l10n`

Install the UK/GB package, for example:
`sudo apt install libreoffice-l10n-en-gb`

Then start LO, and select it via `Tools/Options/Languages` menu.

Comment: thankyou very much ... I knew it was something like that but didn't know the name of the language pack, or the exact syntax.

Comment: Please upvote my answer, if it is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: That was useful, but for some reason my Libreoffice still indicates 'none' in the 'text language' box, when I try to spellcheck.  No suggested words appear as I type, there is no continuous spellchecking either.